# Express Validator Custom - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou utilizando o `express-validator` em minha api pra validar os dados recebidos, estou criando uma validação customizada pra verificar se o email do usuário já está registrado no sistema porém, não consigo disparar um `throw new Error('Email em uso');` pra função principal do express-validator já que a minha consulta sql é retornada em uma função de callback, logo, se eu utilizar o  `throw new Error` ele é direcionado a função de callback e não à principal.

Meu código:

```
app.post('/account/new/validate', [
    body('emailRegistro')
        .isLength({ min: 5, max: 50 })
        .isEmail()
        .custom((emailRegistro) => {
            accountModel.VerificarEmailExistente(sql, emailRegistro, (error, result) => {
                console.log("Chegou aqui - 1");
                if(result.length !== 0){
                    console.log("Chegou aqui - 2");
                    throw new Error('Email em uso'); //Erro disparado a função de callback do sql.query, esse erro precisa ir para a função principal
                    return;
                }
            });
        })
        .withMessage('Email Inválido')
], (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        validationResult(req).throw();
        //Validações concluídas
        console.log("OK");
    }catch(err){
        //Retorno dos erros de validação
        return res.json({ errors: err.mapped() });
    }
});
```

Como eu já disse, quando o email já existe ele dispara um erro à função de callback, e, como ela não está circundada por `try{} catch(){}` a minha aplicação para:

[image: Erro gerado ao enviar um email em uso à minha api]

Como eu posso sair dessa situação e disparar um erro para a função principal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá! Mantenedor do express-validator aqui :)

Você deve usar promises para tornar o seu validador assíncrono no express-validator.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
.custom((emailRegistro) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        accountModel.VerificarEmailExistente(sql, emailRegistro, (error, result) => {
            if(result.length !== 0){
                reject(new Error('Email em uso'));
            } else {
              resolve();
            }
        });
    });
})
```

P.S.: validadores `.custom()` usam a mensagem do `Error` lançado. Então você  não precisa usar `.withMessage()` depois dele.